# How to plot a Cumulative distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4NDD.png)

Currently, I am asked to plot the cumulative distribution in R. I have no idea how to go about it. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: you need to share your data (try `dput(yourdata)` ) and an attempt at the problem.

Comment: You have you looked at the example from the stats package? Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function ecdf() https://rpubs.com/tgjohnst/cumulative_plotting

Comment: It seems you truly have no idea. Some tips: 
dnorm(): normal density funciton;  pnorm() : cumulative density function.
Example: plot(curve(pnorm(x),-3,3))

Comment: @Mike I thought I added a picture of my data.    F(x) = { 0 : for x < 1, 1/10 : for 1<=x<=4, 3/10 : for 4<=x<=6, 6/10: for 6<=x<=8, 10/10: for 8<= x

Comment: so pictures don't help much, ideally you would submit your data with `dput()` which would allow us to copy and paste your data in our r session so we know we are working with the same data.

Comment: @RicardoVillalba I have tried it : val  <- c(0 , 1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10)
CDF  <- ecdf(val)
plot(CDF). The problem is x-axis. In R , the graph does not correspond to the required x range in my data, namely, x = {0,1,4,6,8}

Comment: @Mike Here is my attempt : val <- c(0 , 1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10) CDF <- ecdf(val) plot(CDF). The x-axis does not correspond to my need. x -axis should be {0,1,4,6,8}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a discrete distribution you can write it out and don't need `ecdf()` Note I am using the percentages from the figure you posted in the question. you can also write this as a function if you case become more complicated but I started here.

```
val <- c(0 , 1/10, 1/10,1/10,3/10, 3/10, 6/10,6/10, 10/10)

x <- 0:8


yz <- data.frame( x=x,val = val)


plot(yz$x, yz$val)
```